# Generic EnumSet in signature

Tags: java

I want to write a method that takes in an EnumSet, adds Enum objects to the set, and then output my new modified EnumSet. I am not too sure how to write the signature of this method. After a bit of browsing I have the following as my signature:

```
public <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet<E> addIntervals(EnumSet<E> set)
```

However, when I reference set in my method, I cannot use methods associated with that EnumSet. Am I approaching this correctly?

```
enum Week {
    SUN(0), MON(1), TUE(2), WED(3), THU(4), FRI(5), SAT(6)}
```

Here is my enum set. For example, let's say we want to add odd days of the week to an empty EnumSet.

```
 public <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet<E> addIntervals(EnumSet<E> set) {
     ...
     for (Week day : oddWeekDays) {
          set.add(day);
```

set should have type EnumSet, and I should be able to add the odd days of the week like Week.MON or Week.WED. However, in IntelliJ it says "Cannot resolve method 'add'".

Thanks

EDIT:

So let's say I have the above Week EnumSet and I have a Month EnumSet:

```
enum Month{
      DAY_1(0), DAY_2(1) ... DAY_31(30)}
```

Can I write a function that can generically take in either of these EnumSets?

Comment: Show us the code you've tried to "reference set in my method", and what happens when you "cannot use methods associated with that EnumSet", please.

Comment: 1. How can you assume `E` is `Week`? 2. There's no `Set.add()` that takes an array. You'll need something like `addAll(Arrays.asList(array))`. 3. `Week` is very confusing name for what should be `DayOfWeek`.

Comment: 1. I want my method to know what type E is given what I passed in as a parameter.
2. What if I just wanted to add each individual Enum then? Ignote Week.values().
3. This is a quick write-up to try to demonstrate what I want.

Comment: "I want my method to know what type E is given what I passed in as a parameter" Great... except Java uses type erasure, so you can't tell what E is at run time.

Comment: *Can I write a function that can generically take in either of these EnumSets?* Not unless they share a unique interface.

Comment: @shmosel They do share a unique interface

Comment: Then you should be able to do `<E extends Enum<E> & MyInterface>` to restrict the input type. But you still won't be able to add to the set.

Comment: So I do have the add method implemented for EnumSets. Why won't it be able to add to the set?

Comment: Because you can't know which type it is of those two. You can only add a `Day` to a `Set<Day>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet<E> addIntervals(EnumSet<E> set) {
  ...
  for (Week day : oddWeekDays) {
    set.add(day);
```

This method signature says "I accept arbitrary `EnumSet` instances" (since `E` extends `Enum`), yet you're trying to add a concrete `Week` type to the set. What would you expect to happen if, for example, you passed in an `EnumSet<Day>` type to `addIntervals()`?

If you intend to only add `Week` instances to your set, simply make your method accept an `EnumSet<Week>`, and get rid of the `E` generic type.

If you really do intend to accept arbitrary `EnumSet<E>` instances please add more details about what you're [actually trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to your question.

Comment: Just added something. Hopefully the edit makes my point clear?

Comment: It's still not clear what you're actually trying to do, though. Your original `addIntervals()` example could only possibly ever work with `EnumSet<Week>`. Can you share a concrete example of what you're trying to accomplish? As shmosel notes you could change all your enums to share a common interface, but that won't work for enums you don't own.

Comment: So the goal of my method is to take in different empty EnumSets (like Week and Month), add all the days of the week (or month) to the empty EnumSet, and return the EnumSet.

Comment: In that case, just use [`EnumSet.allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf-java.lang.Class-). But if for whatever reason that wouldn't work, you'd just create separate method for each desired enum.